# ParseFloat keeps converting round or convert

Tags: javascript

im having a issue in converting my input numbers, when is inserted 1,050000, instead of giving me the result of 1.050000, it gives me 1.000000.

```
parseFloat("1,050000").toFixed(6).toString()
```

Comment: Why would it give `1.050000` ? `coma` is not `decimal`

Comment: what regional settings are you using on your browser/OS

Comment: @QBM5, `parseFloat` works irrespective of internationalization settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the design of `parseFloat`. It is not designed to "understand" commas as a decimal separator.

Infact, `parseFloat` will stop parsing your string altogether whenever it encounters anything other than +, -, number, exponent or decimal point.

So, in this case, it only considers your input as `1`. `toFixed(6)` makes sure you get six digits after the decimal, hence the output `1.000000`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using a comma, instead of a decimal dot. Try this instead:

`parseFloat("1.050000").toFixed(6).toString()`

Comment: That is a rationalization thing, he code is perfectly valid in alot of regionalized languages

Comment: @QBM5 - rationalization --> internationalization?

Comment: @enhzflep - guess I was never taught to view those two words differently

Comment: @QBM5 - Lol. (they're as different as feather and brick) Anyhow, your initial comment is incorrect actually. For more, see the **Description**, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat :)

Comment: @QBM5 the `parseFloat()` function expects the JavaScript numeric constant syntax.

Comment: @enhzflep - sorry there was definitely a type in there i did not see

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your comma separated number with

```
var number = "1,050000";
var changedNumber  = number.replace(/,/g, '.')
alert(parseFloat(changedNumber).toFixed(6).toString())
```

Comment: If `var number = "1,0500,00,5000";`